How do I render different languages on different routes?
I have translated my react components with i18next. When I switch the language, how do I route it like this for localhost:3000/en using react-router? It should automatically switch to /se when I switch to for example, Swedish.
App.jsx with my routes =>
<ThemeProvider defaultTheme='light' storageKey='vite-ui-theme'>
      <SelectedContext.Provider value={{ selected, setSelected }}> 
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
          <Toaster />
          <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            <Router>
              <div className='w-screen'>
              <LoadingBarComponent />
                {/* Render the appropriate component based on the route */}
                <Navigation userProfile={userProfile}/>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path='*' element={<ErrorPage />} />
                  <Route path="/" element={<Home userPlan={userPlan} stripeID={stripeID} />} />
                  <Route path='/terms' element={<Terms />} />
                  <Route path='/create' element={<Dashboard userPlan={userPlan} userProfile={userProfile} />} />
                  <Route path='/create/add' element={<Create userPlan={userPlan} />} />
                  <Route path='/create/tag/:category' element={<Dubs />} />
                  <Route path='/Signup' element={<Signup />} />
                  <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                  <Route path='/reset-password' element={<ResetPass />} />
                  <Route path='/reset-password/reset' element={<NewPassword />} />
                  <Route path='/pricing' element={<Pricing stripeID={stripeID} userPlan={userPlan} />} />
                  <Route path='/credits' element={<Credits credits={credits} setCredits={setCredits} stripeID={stripeID} />} />
                  <Route path='/create/editor/:voiceName' element={<Editor user={user} credits={credits} setCredits={setCredits} userPlan={userPlan} />} />
                  <Route path='/success/confirm' element={<ConfirmEmail />} />
                  <Route path='/payment/success' element={<PaymentSuccess />} />
                  <Route path='/billing' element={<Billing user={user} userPlan={userPlan} stripeID={stripeID} />} />
                  <Route path='/create/search' element={<SearchMobile />} />
                  <Route path='/login-popup' element={<LoginPopup />} />
                  <Route path='/voices'  element={<MyVoices user={user} userPlan={userPlan} />} />
                  <Route path='/profile/settings' element={<SettingsPage />} />
                </Routes>
                <FooterComponent />
              </div>
            </Router>
          </Elements>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </SelectedContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>

Footer.jsx where I switch the language =>
const Footer = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(navigator.language.slice(0,2) || "en");
  
  const languageSum = {
    en: "English",
    sv: "Swedish"
  }

  const getLanguage = (language) => {
    return languageSum[language]
  }

  const openInNewTab = (url) => {
    window.open(url, "_blank", "noreferrer");
  };

  const handleLanguageClick = (language) => {
    i18next.changeLanguage(language);
    setLanguage(language);
    console.log("set language", language);
  };


  return (
    <div className="pt-[160px]">
      <div className="pt-[160px]">
        <Separator />
      </div>
        <div id="footer-container" className="pt-[35px] flex flex-row space-x-2 justify-center">
        <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1">
          <div className="flex-row flex space-x-1">
            <div id="footer-text" className="flex items-center">
              <img id="footer-logo" src={Logo} className="w-[25px] h-[25px]" alt="logo"></img>
              <h2 id="footer-name" className="text-xl font-semibold">VoiceOvery</h2>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownMenuTrigger>
                    <Button>
                      <Globe className="mr-1" /> {getLanguage(language)}
                    </Button>
                </DropdownMenuTrigger>
                <DropdownMenuContent>
                  <DropdownMenuLabel>Languages</DropdownMenuLabel>
                  <DropdownMenuSeparator />
                  <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleLanguageClick("en")}>English</DropdownMenuItem>
                  <DropdownMenuItem>German</DropdownMenuItem>
                  <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleLanguageClick("sv")}>Swedish</DropdownMenuItem>
                  <DropdownMenuItem>Spanish</DropdownMenuItem>
                </DropdownMenuContent>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </div>

Here is my i18next config =>
const options = {
  order: ['querystring', 'navigator'],
  lookupQuerystring: 'lng'
}

i18next

  .use(initReactI18next)
  // Initialize the i18next instance.
  .init({
    // Default langauge
    detection: options,
    lng: navigator.language || "en",

    // Fallback language
    fallbackLng: "en",

    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },

    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          ...landingEn,
          ...faqEn,
          ...pricingEn,
          ...loginEn,
          ...metaEn,
          ...categoriesEn
        }
      },
      sv: {
        translation: {
          ...landingSe,
          ...faqSe,
          ...pricingSe,
          ...loginSe,
          ...metaSe,
          ...categoriesSe
        }
      }
    }
  });

Any help would be much appreciated! Can't seem to figure it out. I have tried

Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76838983/8690857

@DrewReese I found this when looking but it got really messy trying to implement it, and I couldn't get it to work will try again.
